# Using UPDATE to update user data in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have run into an issue with my Administrator panel. I have an issue where when you try to update the profile by having the users preferences, it tends to keep the user data the same. I do not have any issues.

Listed below is the code for user.php

```
<?php

    include 'includes/db.php';
    include 'includes/protect.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit_update'])){

        $firstName = $_POST['fname'];
        $lastName = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $aboutMe = $_POST['about_me'];

        $query = "UPDATE users 
                  SET firstName = '$firstName', 
                      lastName = '$lastName', 
                      email = '$email', 
                      about_me = '$aboutMe', 
                  WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";

        $edit_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }   
?>
```

Comment: You have an extra comma in `'$aboutMe', `

Comment: You have some serious SQL injection issues in this code - if you have been running this for 10 months already, fix it quickly!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: 1/ To avoid and understand why this is sensible to SQL injection : http://bobby-tables.com/ 2/ You have an extra `,` in `'$aboutMe',` 3/ The anwser about the `{ ... }` when you use an array should help you too. 4/ With prepare statement to avoid SQL injection you should avoid problem 3/

Comment: @halfer I have just run into this issue and I've been dealing with it for about 30 minutes.

Comment: Ah @Bubby, I understand. Your original question started with "10 months later", which was confusing - I think this meant it was 10 months since your last question, rather than you'd been running this code for 10 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sure shot issue is with your `$_SESSION[email]`. But I think you also need few changes on your existing code. You can try like this way-

1. Check value is exits or not before assigning the `$_POST` variable using `isset()` here I've assigned **empty string** by default you can change it as per your requirement. Also see how can you escape using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
2. Put your `$_SESSION['email']` variable to a new variable in that case I used `$sess_email`. (this will be more readable)
3. Remove extra comma(`,`) that you've put inside your `UPDATE` query.

```html
<?php
    $firstName = isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : "" ;
    $lastName = isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : "";
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
    $aboutMe = isset($_POST['about_me']) ? $_POST['about_me'] : "";
    $ses_email = isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email'] : "";

    $query = "UPDATE users SET firstName = '$firstName', lastName = '$lastName', email = '$email', about_me = '$aboutMe' WHERE email = '$sess_email'";
    $edit_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>
```

I also urge you to see how you can easily prevent SQL Injection if you use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Using arrays in double quotes need curly braces around them.

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET firstName = '$firstName', lastName = '$lastName', email = '$email', about_me = '$aboutMe' WHERE email = '{$_SESSION['email']}'";
```

Comment: This will still not run, because of the comma issue.

Comment: Yea missed that.

Answer (score 1):

As [@halfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158689/using-update-to-update-user-data-in-mysql/51158937#comment89300875_51158689) pointed out in the comments. You should seriously change your method to generate SQL statements to avoid [SQL Injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Basically, a user can enter any text, can circumvent your query, and write their own SQL statements. Like a user adding `'; DROP TABLE users; --` as their `firstName`.

The easiest way to start is to utilize [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This will not only secure your code more, but also reduce the chance of syntatical errors when juggling quotes for your query statements.